# Android app doens't use Color.RED when launched from the device

Tags: android, device, launch

So, I'm a beginner developing an android app with eclipse.
When I launch it with Eclipse (to the real device) it goes as expected, but when I launch it after, from the device menu like any other app, it goes different.

The app is supposed to red out some imagebuttons, and grey out after pressing six of them. The thing is, when I launch it from the phone it immediately greys them out, not beginning with the red. I have no clue what it might be, should I post the code part? Does it make a difference?

Comment: The code matters, and more importantly, the layout file. Otherwise the most people can do is blindly answers random aspects of the issue.

Comment: Posting the code may help, yes. My suspicion is that you are seeing the same activity being resumed rather than a new one being created, and it is saving the button state, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Try killing the app. use the back button or actually download a app managing utility to see if the app was correctly closed.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, otherwise this issue is not clear enough.